# Порядок данных в таблице

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Строки распологаются в произвольном порядке в таблице. Тоесть нет гарантии что если я внес в таблицу первым  строку "first" а затем второю строку "second"....

Теперь при выборке нету гарантии что именно при LIMIT 1 без ORDER_BY первой будет запись 
"first"? В кого практически такие ситуации были или это только теория?

Второй вопрос если нету поля время добавления строки и не пользоваться PRIMARY_KEY   как узнать и выбрать данные которое раньше добавились ?

Comment: 1. использовать primary key
2. никак без primary key или даты.

Comment: @ua6xh, и каким же это образом primary key позволяет решить эти задачи?

Видимо Вы подразумеваете, что primary key **обязательно** д.б. *int* **и** *autoincrement*. Но, в общем случае, это не так.

Answer (score 1):

...primary key может быть не только не int, а вообще может состоять из нескольких полей.
Кроме того, это [не теория](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6977e/2).
И даже если int и auto_increment (который не менять при вставке или изменении), то никаких гарантий нет.
На практике [был глюк](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1534/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) на Хэшкоде, когда limit с сортировкой, но по неуникальному полю приводил к произвольному порядку для select'в иногда друг за другом. Пусть не совсем вариант из вопроса, но дает понятие о том, что выборка и порядок в ней следует указывать принудительно.